# Read Telegram channel from Node JS

Tags: node.js, telegram

I am creating an application in Node Js that needs to read a message from a Telegram channel, does anyone know how to do it?

I found a lot of information about creating a Telegram Bot, but that does not help. To read information from a public Telegram channel, no bot should be needed.

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Please provide code samples of what you have written thus far. It's hard to give you any help without seeing what sort of nodejs telegram dependency you're using, etc.

Comment: At the moment I have only used the telegram-bot-api library of Nodejs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/telegram-bot-api). But I used this library to create a Telegram bot. Can not be used to read messages from a channel. Thanks

Comment: Would the `getChat` method not be what you want to be able to read messages out of a channel?

Comment: is the bot an admin on the channel? and are the messages you want to read new messages (or old messages)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use telegram mtproto api.
some good efrence is here :

```
https://openbase.io/js/@mtproto/core/documentation
https://core.telegram.org/methods
```